# AutoMapper does not update Collection items

Tags: c#, automapper

I try to use AutoMapper to map models to dtos. The first try uses EF-Core but I was able to eliminate EF-Core and reproduce that without it.

I reproduced the behaviour in this [DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SbRcOE).
(Old DEMO using EF-Core is [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/w0Q3Mi).)

*TL;DR*

It seams that this will not work:

```
var container = new Container("Container-Id 000", new List<Item> { new Item("Item-Id 000") { Name = "Item-Name" } });
var containerModel = mapper.Map<ContainerModel>(container);

// apply changes
container.Items[0].Name += " -- changed";

// update model
mapper.Map(container, containerModel);

// at this point the item does not contain the correct name:
container.Items[0].Name != containerModel.Items[0].Name   !!!!!
```

*Long explanation:*

The Dto's and models have the following structure:

```
Container
    + Id: string { get; }
    + Items: IReadOnlyList<Item> { get; }

Item
    + Id: string { get; }
    + Name: string { get; set; }

ContainerModel
    + Id: string { get; set; }
    + Items: List<ItemModel> { get; set; }

ItemModel
    + Id: string { get; set; }
    + Name: string { get; set; }
```

The AutoMapper-Configuration is (maybe that's the point where I'm missing something):

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(
    cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Container, ContainerModel>(MemberList.None)
                .EqualityComparison((src, dst) => src.Id == dst.Id)
                .ForMember(dst => dst.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
                .ForMember(dst => dst.Items, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Items));
            cfg.CreateMap<ContainerModel, Container>(MemberList.None)
                .EqualityComparison((src, dst) => src.Id == dst.Id)
                .ForMember(dst => dst.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
                .ForMember(dst => dst.Items, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Items));

            cfg.CreateMap<IReadOnlyList<Item>, List<ItemModel>>(MemberList.None)
                .ConstructUsing((src, ctx) => src.Select(ctx.Mapper.Map<ItemModel>).ToList());
            cfg.CreateMap<List<ItemModel>, IReadOnlyList<Item>>(MemberList.None)
                .ConstructUsing((src, ctx) => src.Select(ctx.Mapper.Map<Item>).ToList().AsReadOnly());

            cfg.CreateMap<Item, ItemModel>(MemberList.None)
                .EqualityComparison((src, dst) => src.Id == dst.Id)
                .ForMember(dst => dst.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
                .ForMember(dst => dst.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name));
            cfg.CreateMap<ItemModel, Item>(MemberList.None)
                .EqualityComparison((src, dst) => src.Id == dst.Id)
                .ForMember(dst => dst.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
                .ForMember(dst => dst.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name));
        });
var result = config.CreateMapper();
result.ConfigurationProvider.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
return result;
```

I created a dto-instance and mapped them successfully to the model. (I also tested the way back from model to dto that also works but is not needed to reproduce the problem.)

```
var mapper = CreateMapper();

var container = new Container("Container-Id 000", new List<Item> { new Item("Item-Id 000") { Name = "Item-Name" } });
var containerModel = mapper.Map<ContainerModel>(container);

// apply changes
container.Items[0].Name += " -- changed";

// update model
mapper.Map(container, containerModel);

Console.WriteLine($"Src.Name: {container.Items[0].Name}");
Console.WriteLine($"Dst.Name: {containerModel.Items[0].Name}");
if (container.Items[0].Name != containerModel.Items[0].Name)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("The names of dto and model doesn't match!");
}
```

The output printed before the exception has thrown shows the problem:

```
Src.Name: Item-Name -- changed
Dst.Name: Item-Name
```

The specified exception is thrown - but shouldn't (in my opinion).

I think the problem is `mapper.Map(readContainer, readContainerModel);`.
I specified an equality comparision to help AutoMapper to find the correct instances but without luck.

What am I missing here? What do I have to do to fix that issue?

All that persistence code is wrapped into a small framework and should be transparent to my colleques. All they have to do is specifying the dtos,  models ans mapping profile. The framework does not know about "navigations". Yes I'm able to create code that analyses all the navigations of the model-types and try to find an equivalent dto and foreach all the properties and updates all instances manuelly. But that seams to treat much pain and errors what's the reason I tried the automated mapping.

*Why do I need `mapper.Map(src, dst)`?*

All that works together with EF-Core and a small persistence framework for my colleques. I tried using `Persist()` and `InsertOrUpdate` (that the preferred method) but I found that [issue report for AutoMapper.Collection](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection.EFCore/issues/30). The `InsertOrUpdate`-method is broken. The specified workarround is what I was trying to use until the issue is fixed - but it doesn't solve the problem.

I also found that article [WHY MAPPING DTOS TO ENTITIES USING AUTOMAPPER AND ENTITYFRAMEWORK IS HORRIBLE](https://rogerjohansson.blog/2013/12/01/why-mapping-dtos-to-entities-using-automapper-and-entityframework-is-horrible/) containing the same trick. I don't care about the created model instances that AutoMapper will produce for every collection item. I'm also not easyly able to forward the DbContext to the mapping functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. I added this to map the collections to the AutoMapper configuration:

```
cfg.CreateMap<IReadOnlyList<Item>, List<ItemModel>>(MemberList.None)
    .ConstructUsing((src, ctx) => src.Select(ctx.Mapper.Map<ItemModel>).ToList());
cfg.CreateMap<List<ItemModel>, IReadOnlyList<Item>>(MemberList.None)
    .ConstructUsing((src, ctx) => src.Select(ctx.Mapper.Map<Item>).ToList().AsReadOnly());
```

It seams that this will prevent AutoMapper from working correctly.

The solution is to remove both printed lines and add the following instead:

```
cfg.AddCollectionMappers();
```

I added the explicit collection mappings because I underestimated the power of `AddCollectionMappers` because I'm using immutable objects and interfaces to `IReadOnlyList<>` and `IReadOnlyDictionary<,>` and I was wrongly of the opinion that AutoMapper was not able to handle that. My fault.

See the working [DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9VM3VK).

Comment: If this is the solution to your problem, then you should mark this as "Accepted Answer".

Comment: @atiyar Yes I will. But you've to wait 2 days before you can mark it as "Accepted Answer". And I still have to wait 2 hours.